# LinQ XML contains in where clause

Tags: linq-to-xml

```
 var geoSettings = (from c in geoFields.Elements("Maps").Elements("Map")
                              select new
                              {
                                  loc = c.Element("Location").Value
                              }).Distinct().Intersect(from p in terrainFields.Elements("Maps").Elements("Map")
                                                      select new
                                                      {
                                                          loc = p.Element("Location").Value
                                                      });

       var flightCheck = from x in baseStations.Elements("BaseStation").Elements("Station")
                         //  where (geoSettings.Location.Contains(x.Element("Location").Value))
                         select new
                         {
                             Flights = x.Element("FlightName").Value,
                             loc = x.Element("Location").Value
                         };
```

Both Maps and BaseStation are xml files.I'm stuck at //  where(geoSettings.Location.Contains(x.Element("Location").Value))
geoSettings is an IEnumerable.How can i get the "Location"?

Answer (score 0):

Use a join instead

```
var flightCheck = from x in baseStations.Elements("BaseStation").Elements("Station")
                  join y in geoSettings.Location on x x.Element("Location").Value equals y.Value                             
                  select new
                  {
                      Flights = x.Element("FlightName").Value,
                      loc = x.Element("Location").Value
                  };
```

That will give you only elements from x where there is a matching element in y.

Comment: Cant access geoSettings.Location this way because geoSettings is of type IEnumerable

Comment: I used joins and it worked , thanks for the idea but still geoSettings.Location is incorrect so i'm unable to tag your response as the right answer.

Answer (score 0):

`geoSettings` is an IEnumerable. *`geoSettings.loc` isn't*. (I assume you mean `loc`, not `Location`, because your code doesn't contain the latter...)

So you can further understand what I mean, note that `geoSettings[n].loc` is valid, but `geoSettings.loc[n]` is not.

So...you're going to need to use `Any()` instead of `Contains()`, as in "if anything in my collection of geoSettings elements has a matching location":

```
var flightCheck = from x in baseStations.Elements("BaseStation").Elements("Station")
                  where geoSettings.Any(geo => geo.loc.Contains(x.Element("Location").Value)
                  select new
                  {
                      Flights = x.Element("FlightName").Value,
                      loc = x.Element("Location").Value
                  };
```

---

Side note: if you really are only selecting one value into `geoSettings`, instead of making it a collection of anonymous types (with a single property `loc`), just make it a collection of strings and select only the value. Then you can use `Contains()` and save making a whole bunch of new objects.